# Storing the value of a cell in a variable from different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

This line of code always comes back with 0 value....

```
MonTot = Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:A200").Find(Num).Offset(0, 20).Value
```

Yet almost the exact same syntax and in a IF statement it works how it should

```
 If Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:A200").Find(Num).Offset(0, 19) = 0.6 Then
```

Why will the first line of code not pull the value of the cell in the specified location?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a value in the cell that is 20 columns to the right of where it finds `Num` in column A.  that is Column `U`

Comment: What did you declare `MonTot` as, and why do you have `20` as an offset in one line and `19` in the other?

Comment: Also - it is bad practice to chain member calls after `.Find`, without first testing that the `Find` was successful.

Comment: the Find was tested and it did work. But Scott I did forgot that 0 is counted as the first column, so that did put it one column past the desired column. Thank you both for the quick replies.